# Как в Jenkins запустить последний успешный build проекта?

Tags: git, github, jenkins, непрерывная-интеграция

Есть 2 jobs, в них один и тот же проект;
один job запускается только тогда, когда обнаруживается новая версия git;
второй job должен запускать последнюю версию git, build которой был успешным в 1-ом job.

Как сделать, чтобы 2-ой job запускал последний успешный build 1-го job?

Comment: Периодически возвращаюсь к этому вопросу-  самому интересен ответ.

Comment: @NickVolynkin ответ простой -- переехать на ТимСити :D. Последнее время имею дело с Дженкинсом -- и все больше понимаю, насколько классный продукт сделали джетбрейнсовцы.

Comment: @andreycha мы подумываем про GitLab CI,  потому что уже используем сам GitLab.

Answer (score 2):

Я не очень большой специалист в jenkins, но я бы делал так. Первая задача по выполнению компиляции проекта, копирует скомпилированные файлы, нужные для работы программы, в отдельную папку. Грубо говоря, она делает инсталляцию.

Вторая задача при запуске проверяет наличие файлов в папке и запускает, если они есть. Так как неудачная компиляция проекта в первом случае не будет удалять скомпилированные файлы с специальной папки, то вторая задача всегда будет иметь возможность запускать "последний успешный билд".

Comment: еще лучше, если есть подготовленный репозиторий для билдов (если результат - джарники или докер-контейнеры) - в этом случае все становится совсем красиво

Answer (score 0):

Способов много. Я бы в первом проекте сохранял GIT_COMMIT в файл (`echo GIT_COMMIT=$GIT_COMMIT > env.properties`, а во втором проекте копировал бы этот файл из последней успешной сборки первого проекта (плагин [Copy artifact](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/Copy+Artifact+Plugin)) и использовал бы в shell-скрипте или импортировал информацию плагином [EnvInject](https://wiki.jenkins-ci.org/display/JENKINS/EnvInject+Plugin), что безопаснее.

А [большие мальчики](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5510978/in-hudson-how-do-i-get-the-current-builds-git-commit-sha) делают HTTP-запрос к API (URL вида `http://твой_сервер/job/твой_проект/lastStableBuild/api/json?tree=actions[lastBuiltRevision[branch[*]]]`) и анализируют полученный JSON

Answer (score 0):

В идеальной CI системе эта схема должна работать так:

- первый билд делает сборку и публикует результат (например, бинарники) в качестве артефакта
- второй билд должен зависеть от первого: брать из последнего успешного первого билда его артефакты и запускаться либо вручную, либо автоматически

В ТимСити, например, это все есть из коробки. Что касается Дженкинса:

- артефакты для первого билда он сгенерит
- плагин Copy Artifacts поможет второму билду скопировать артефакты из первого билда (причем нужно указать, что брать нужно из Last successful build), а автоматического запуска второго билда [есть разные способы](https://zeroturnaround.com/rebellabs/how-to-use-jenkins-for-job-chaining-and-visualizations/), в т.ч. и встроенные